# Can the TLE epoch be listed as in the future? How?

Tags: artificial-satellite, time, orbit-determination

Can the epoch time of a TLE be in the future?

Context: ISS TLE from [Heavens Above](https://www.heavens-above.com/passdetails.aspx?&satid=25544&mjd=58311.3330090626)

1 25544U 98067A   18193.60071450  .00016717  00000-0  10270-3 0  9013 
2 25544  51.6401 252.0472 0003848 304.4303  55.6485 15.53943096  2461

This gives the date 12 July ~2pm UTC, but the current time is ~9am UTC. Is this a mistake?

Comment: In general, it can, showing the *predicted* position. I'm not sure about this specific case; it's sufficient to compute the orbit and position at arbitrary not too distant time (what the site needs), but obviously that's a calculated TLE, not measured, so not as accurate.

Comment: I thought this question has been answered here before, and that the answer went into some detail about why this is done from time to time, but I can't find any trace of that now. @PearsonArtPhoto does this issue look familliar?

Comment: @PennyPlayer thanks for the accept, but why not wait a few days to see if further answers are posted? It's okay to accept right away, but it sometimes discourages others from adding additional, also informative answers. Maybe something I've said is incorrect or needs clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this question has been answered here before, and that the answer went into some detail about why this is done from time to time, but I can't find any trace of that now.

The epoch *could, technically, potentially*, be in the past or the future by quite a lot, as long as the satellite isn't falling too quickly, since the SGP4 algorithm propagation is predictable and deterministic.

In other words, the epoch could be next year, as long as when you run a recent, supported SPG4 propagator it produces a fairly accurate answer now. However, most people *interpret* the epoch as the time of best accuracy, though it doesn't necessarily *have to be*.

So I think the answer to the limited question

> Can the TLE epoch be listed as in the future?

is yes it could be. Nothing mathematically prevents that from happening as long as at the current epoch (i.e. now) SPG4 returns a fairly accurate answer that hasn't burned up in the Earth's atmosphere yet, and this is because SPG4 is predictable and deterministic.

**update:** I went to Space-Track.org and downloaded all TLEs issued on day numbers 191 and 192 of 2018. You can see there are many issued with epochs days or (not shown) months in the past, and some stragglers with epochs many days into the future. That the TLEs with epochs in the future are higher altitude is probably meaningful. Plotted with https://pastebin.com/LaxR6p4Y

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From Space-Track.Org [FAQ](https://www.space-track.org/documentation#/faq)

> TLEs can contain future epochs.
>
> About 20 satellites are categorized as "multi-day objects" because their period is so large. Consequently, our data provider propagates the epoch into the future based on perigee to enable better tracking by available sensors when the object finally comes back into view.
>
> An example is Object 10370 with a 5683.23 minute period.

This is **an** explanation, but it wouldn't apply to the ISS.

Comment: Interesting answer! Based on what they've said there, I've now asked [Is SGP4 propagation necessarily more accurate near the epoch chosen for TLE generation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29751/12102)

Comment: Good point! I know older methods like Gauss' are and I just assumed that the same would apply to SGP4... looking forward to an answer.